# php display mysql table in html

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am currently working a tutorial  on php and mysql.I am currently working on a script which should read data from sql database and show that data in html table.I have a problem where the table is generated with empty fields. It has correct number of fields but those fields are empty.

Here is my php script:

```
<?php
require "init.php";

$select = "select * from ScoresTest";
$sqlSel = mysqli_query($con,$select);
if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlSel)>0)
{

    echo("Works");
}
echo"<table border = '1'>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Score</th>
</tr>";
while($row  = mysqli_fetch_row($sqlSel))
{

    echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['USERNAME'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['SCORES'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo"</table>";


?>
```

Here is how the result looks like: 
[Html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tibDT.png)

Number of rows in my table is ok but the fields are empty.Why?

Comment: `mysqli_error($con)` shows you what? undefined indexes maybe?

Comment: Try printing $row inside the while loop, you will get the keys.

Comment: @Nagesh they're already doing that.

Comment: you're using the wrong function/method of retrieval here. RTM.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I tried mysqli_error($con), it shows nohing

Comment: you sure you're running this off a webserver and using the right protocol? I told already up there; you're using the wrong method.

Comment: Keys are wrong, the HTML table shows "Username", and you are printing the USERNAME, all in capital.

Comment: Change `"select * from ScoresTest"` by `"select username as USERNAME,  scores as SCORES from ScoresTest"` (replace the "username" and "scores" by the right name of your column but empty field might be because you your `$row['USERNAME'] ` and  ` $row['SCORES']` are not the right name)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Sorry, I am not sure if I understood you well.I am running this script on a webserver , I managed to retrieve my data as json array and it works, but this method with html table doesn't

Comment: `echo("Works");` if that doesn't show up, then your query failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual on `fetch_row()` https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

shows using the following array keys `$row[0], $row[1]`.

But you're using the column names.

In that case, use `fetch_assoc()` https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Plus, make sure those are the actual names and not in another letter case.

PHP's error reporting will (also) help you here https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

**NOTE:** On *NIX, `VAR` and `var` are two different animals.

You also need to run this off a webserver and using the correct protocol.

That's unknownst to us.

Comment: Thank you! I changed to $row[0], $row[1] and it displays the data!

Comment: @CreationApps I did make an edit earlier about using `fetch_assoc()` if you wish to continue using the named array keys.

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be changing mysqli_fetch_row to mysqli_fetch_assoc

```
while($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlSel))
{

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['USERNAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['SCORES'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code,

```
while($row  = mysqli_fetch_row($sqlSel))
{

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['USERNAME'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['SCORES'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Sure if you name of row is $row['USERNAME']? maybe the name of you row is in lowercase or the name of you fields is not correct.
Also you can use the position of the row "for debug"( $row[0], $row[1])